# Merge tag [ml5] into [ml5.js]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

Tags [ml5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ml5) and [ml5.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ml5.js) refer to the same JavaScript library.

I recommend using [ml5.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ml5.js) as the canonical tag for consistency with [p5.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/p5.js), [d3.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/d3.js), etc.  [ml5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ml5) should be a synonym.

---

[ml5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ml5) 41 questions

> Use for any topic related to the machine learning library (usage, models, algorithms)

[ml5.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ml5.js) 16 questions

> ML5 is a Javascript Machine Learning library built on top of Tensorflow.js

Answer (score 4):

I've merged the tags into [ml5.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ml5.js).

I didn't create a synonym, as "ml5" is just a shorter version of "ml5.js"—I don't think the synonym would help anyone find it.